# Objective-c : Accessing variadic arguments in method

Tags: objective-c, c, function, methods, variadic-functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create variable argument methods in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804674/how-to-create-variable-argument-methods-in-objective-c)
>   [Variable number of method parameters in Objective C - Need an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454408/variable-number-of-method-parameters-in-objective-c-need-an-example)

Following is an example of a method having variadic arguments.

```
- (void)numberOfParameters:group,... {
    NSLog(@"%@",group);
}
```

In above method, I know to access the first one of the variadic arguments.
Would you please help me for accessing the others as well?

I am just going through [ObjC.pdf](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html)  & I am reading page number 35 & line number is 4

Comment: Also, questions not related to the Xcode IDE itself **should not use the Xcode tag.** This question would stay the same if you used nano and make to build your iOS apps.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260840/objective-c-implement-method-which-takes-array-of-arguments

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067358/methods-and-optional-parameters

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214652/how-do-i-pass-a-nil-terminted-list-of-strings-to-an-objective-c-function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this almost same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12454862/1357776)

```
-(void)yourMethods:(id)string1, ...{

    NSMutableArray *arguments=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:nil];
    id eachObject;
    va_list argumentList;
    if (string1) 
    {
        [arguments addObject: string1];
        va_start(argumentList, string1); 
        while ((eachObject = va_arg(argumentList, id)))    
        {
             [arguments addObject: eachObject];
        }
        va_end(argumentList);        
     }
    NSLog(@"%@",arguments);
}
```

Call it with **nil** parameter at the end as:

```
[object yourMethods:arg1,arg2,arg3,nil];// object can be self
```

Comment: It should be noted that this method expects a `nil` as the final parameter otherwise it will cause a segmentation fault as it runs off the end of the parameters.

Comment: it should be called as [object yourMethods:arg1,arg2,arg3,nil]; but since the questioner just asked how to access the methods, i had not mentioned how to call the method... but as u mentioned in your comment i have added it in my answer... cheers

Answer (score 3):

One: they're not called "group parameters" (as far as I know), but rather variadic arguments.

Two: the C standard library header `stdarg.h` provides data types and macros for this purpose (that's why I generally suggest to master plain ol' ANSI C first, before making *The Best iPhone App Ever (TM)*...)

```
#include <stdarg.h>

- (void)numberOfParameters:(int)num, ...
{
    int i;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, num);

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        SomeType param = va_arg(args, SomeType);
        // do something with `param'
    }

    va_end(args);
}
```

Here's a [rather good explanation](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson17.html) on this topic.